# File encryption in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am developing a react native chat app that can also send files(image, video, pdf, docx etc) from one user to another. I need to encrypt the file in the app before sending to the server, then the server will in turn send the encrypted file to the intended user. I am looking for an encryption module for files in react native but I can't seem to find one. All I found are AES text encryption modules. Can someone suggest me what should I use?

I could also zip the files with passwords, instead of encrypting the files. But no modules provide zip with password like react-native-zip-archive. Only unzip with password. If I can zip files with passwords in react native that should solve my problem too.